# What do you call or term for macro with ##

Tags: c++, c

For example I have,

```
#define (name) ##name
```

What is the term for ##name?

Thanks!

Comment: The name for that is 'broken'; the `##` must separate two tokens and in your example, does not.  The C11 standard calls it 'The `##` operator': _§6.10.3.3 The ## operator
**Constraints**
1 A `##` preprocessing token shall not occur at the beginning or at the end of a replacement
list for either form of macro definition._

Comment: AS per @Acme ## is a macro concatenation operator,and it is correct ,but at least it requires two tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Concat operator i believe. Also called token pasting or token concatenation operator. The `##` preprocessing operator performs token pasting. When a macro is expanded, the two tokens on either side of each `##` operator are combined into a single token, which then replaces the `##` and the two original tokens in the macro expansion. Usually both will be identifiers, or one will be an identifier and the other a preprocessing number. When pasted, they make a longer identifier.

See here - [## Operator (Macro Concatenation)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/ilcrefer17.htm)